# Share internet access with route

Tags: linux, route

I'm trying to share internet connection of a linux machine with another machine.

Both created in vmbox, PC A has a internal network connection, PC B has both an internal and external connection. Dhcpd of vmbox is enabled for internal network, both systems get their internal network IP from this.

PC A -> 10.10.10.2
PC B -> 10.10.10.4  (internal) +  10.0.3.15(external)

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 and IPtables are disabled in both machines.
Machines can ping each other, PC B can ping internet

**PC A ->**

[image]

```
route add default gw 10.10.10.4
```

**PC B ->**

[image]

```
route add default gw 10.0.3.15
```

traceroute from PC A ends with timeout at PC B. For some reasong PC B does not forward the traffic

Answer (score 0):

on pc b:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I want to understand why route is not working. Thank you for the info

Comment: because  external (10.0.3.15) doesn't know where to answer back to 10.10.10.2

Comment: So this task is not possible with route alone?

Comment: add a route on 10.0.3.15, too.

Comment: It is not possible with route alone, you need SNAT / MASQUERADE here.

Comment: On PC B you need this too: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1